# How can I know how close I am to not being able to ask questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, post-ban

I recently got back the privilege of asking questions on StackOverflow. I had lost it due to some questions that were not important, poor-quality, etc. However, I have since reformed my ways, and want to be a productive member of the community. How can I know how close I am to losing this privilege again?

Comment: This does seem like useful information, the fear is that people might use it to stay on the edge of the ban rather than improving their overall question asking ability

Comment: P.s. I'm glad to hear you got back over the line. I did think a few of your questions were excessively downvoted

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't know how close you are to losing your question asking privilege. We don't want people to think they can get away with asking a few low-quality questions because they're far enough away from getting banned.  Always ask high-quality questions.